# Can Share [] command and ParallelTable be used together?

Tags: parallelization

Can Share [] command and ParallelTable  be used together? I mean, does this result in the data exchanging between different cores? A simple example:

```
l={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};

l1={{1,2},{3,4}};

s[{i1_,i2_},i3_,i4_]:={i1,i2}*i3*i4;

s[l1[[1]],i3_,i4_]:=s[l1[[1]],i3,i4]=l1[[1]]*2*i3*i4;

s[l1[[2]],i3_,i4_]:=s[l1[[1]],i3,i4]*(i3+i4);

Share[]

ParallelTable[s[l[[n]],i3,i4],{n,1,3},{i3,1,3},{i4,1,3}]
```

If I run this code, it will compute in this order: 1.use the second definition to get s[{1,2},i3,i4] and store -> 2.use the third definition to compute s[{3,4},i3,i4] and it must to call the information of s[{1,2},i3,i4] because of the definition...Then my question is if the first step and the second are computed in the different cores, how can it to call the information of s[{1,2},i3,i4], or it will compute it again? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to do. Yes, they can be used together but I don't see why you would want to do that.  No, data is not moved between kernels by `Share`. `Share` is not aware of parallel kernels.

Comment: `Share` operates on a single kernel. What I expected your looking for is something like `SetSharedVariable`. That will allow a variable to be accessible by all of the kernels.

Comment: You seem to have some misconceptions about what `Share` does. Please do look it up in the documentation instead of guessing at its purpose.  It has nothing to do with parallelization.

Comment: @ Szabolcs thanks.

Comment: As b3m2a1 said, it might be possible to effectively share this information between kernels usig `SetSharedFunction` and `SetSharedVariable`.  But beware: these will cause the affected function/variable to always be evaluated on the main kernel. This usually comes at a significant peformance cost (no parallelization for that operation + the need to call back to the main kernel).  Careful benchmarking is needed to determine if their use is worthwhile for a specific application.  It would also be necessary to separate the symbol that caches information from the function that computes it.

Comment: This is because caching will necessarily need to be done on the main kernel. To benefit from parallelization at all, at least some of the computation needs to be kept on the parallel kernels.

Comment: I see, and I will have a try. Thanks!